# How to get left table values only (left join)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- `bloodrequest (id,name,Rphone,bloodtype)` as:

  [image]
- `reacheduser (id,Rphonw,Dphone)` as:

  [image]

I want to read all data in `bloodrequest` if `bloodrequest.id` is not equal to `reachedusers.id` where `reachedusers.Dphone!="618159985"`

I have tried left join , subquery  but unfortunately nothing work
hear is some code i tried:

```
SELECT bloodrequest.id, bloodrequest.magac, bloodrequest.bloodType 
FROM bloodrequest 
LEFT JOIN reachedusers on bloodrequest.id != reachedusers.id 
WHERE reachedusers.Dphone != "618159985"
```

i want to check if request id in table bloodrequest  is in reached table where Dphone ="618159985"

if the id is exist but but dphone is not 618159985 i want to read otherwise not

Comment: "if the id is exist but but dphone is not 618159985 i want to read otherwise not" - I think you've just got the logic wrong. Change the ID equality in your join-on to be `bloodrequest.id = reachedusers.id` not !=.

Comment: check pictures i attached  the id 78 is in reached table and dphone is 618159985

Comment: i dont want to read that

Comment: I hope that's not someone's actual phone number.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us the result of your query as it is, and the result you want, we can help you more easily.

Comment: look bloodrequest image i attached i want to  read all data in that table except where the id equel 78 becouase the id is in reachedusers with 618159985  phone

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN (subquery)` to find the rows you want, as in:

```
SELECT
  id, magac, bloodType 
FROM bloodrequest 
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM reachedusers
  WHERE Dphone = "618159985" 
)
```

Comment: thanks you helped me only i changed <> to = and it worked thanks

Comment: i was searching days that little quary

Comment: i am new here and i can't vote i hope others will did it

Comment: @Mohamedabdulkadir Great it was of use to you.